# Sorting a Props array of objects by date before passing to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, graphql-js

I have a component which receives an array of objects called periods

```
[
{id: 4, endDate: "2018-06-30T10:00:00+10:00"}
,{id: 3, endDate: "2017-06-30T10:00:00+10:00"}
,{id: 5, endDate: "2017-06-30T10:00:00+10:00"}
]
```

This is passed down from its parent, which receives via a graphql call.
How can I sort this prop in descending date order and pass it down to a child component to use.
I have tried

```
      const arr = [...this.props.periods];
      const a2 = arr.sort((a, b) => b.endDate.localeCompare(a.endDate));
this.props.periods = a2
.
.
.(child component)
<Dropdown options={this.props.periods} />
```

And receive this error

### TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'periods' of object '#'

Comment: You are getting this error because `props` are read-only and you are assigning a new value to it. Simple solution can be to add the sorted array to state and then pass that state to the child.

Comment: Doesnt the parent also receive it as props from the graphql call?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the props from child component as Props is the read-only.

You can update the state in parent component.

Answer (score 0):

all property in this.props is read-only and you should use state

```
const periods = [...this.props.periods].sort((a, b) => 
b.endDate.localeCompare(a.endDate));

this.setState({periods})

<Dropdown options={this.state.periods} />
```